# Using Rolling Sum on calculated fields, Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, accumulate

I have a column called `Sales` which I need to find the change between current month's and previous month's sales.

For this I've tried:

```
2016 Sales      MonthlyChange   
jan 15401168    
feb 14562410    -838758
mar 13914329    -648081
apr 14471132    556803
maj 13471177    -999955
jun 13207358    -263819
jul 13423816    216458
aug 12322774    -1101042
sep 12109737    -213037
okt 11905915    -203822
nov 12910189    1004274
dec 15136118    2225929
```

I also want to find the **accumulated** change over each month.

```
2016   Sales   MonthlyChange   Acc change
jan 15401168            -838758
feb 14562410    -838758 -1486839
mar 13914329    -648081 -91278
apr 14471132    556803  -443152
maj 13471177    -999955 -1263774
jun 13207358    -263819 -47361
jul 13423816    216458  -884584
aug 12322774    -1101042    -1314079
sep 12109737    -213037 -416859
okt 11905915    -203822 800452
nov 12910189    1004274 3230203
dec 15136118    2225929 2225929
```

`MonthlyChange` is created using `Show value as -> Difference -> (previous)month`. Is it possible to either:

1) Use the MonthlyChange as a `Value` field, insert it to my Pivot Table and conduct a `Show values as -> Running sum`? I haven't found any option to do this

2) Conduct two calculations subsequently on the same column in one PivotTable?

> EDIT

Is it also possible to have the `MonthlyChange`'s first value to correspond to the actual value of jan, i.e. 15401168 instead of a blank value?

Comment: Arithmetically, the cumulative change to a month is simply the difference of the month's value from the `jan` value, so substitue `jan` for `(previous)`  in the `Value field Settings` dialog.

Comment: And you can use `Sales` multiple times in the value area of your Pivot table, with a different value field setting used for each occurrence - so you would be able to display "Sum of Sales", "Difference from (previous)" and "Difference from jan" at the same time in the value area of your pivot table.

Comment: Not sure how you have calculated your "Accumulated Change" values, I agree with first two values shown (though would attribute to `feb` and `mar` rather than `jan` and `feb`, but third one is surely `-838758 + -648081 + 556083` which equals `-930036` and not `-91278` as stated.

Comment: @DMM           Thanks for replying. Yes, I calculated `Acc change` bad. I used it in Excel as a simple formula, but I used the wrong column. I'll fiddle around some in Pivot Table with your other comments to try to grasp how to do that.

Comment: Unless this is part of a much more complex problem, why are you using a pivot table for this? Simple Excel formulae added as columns to your data list would surely be a much simpler approach and you would be able to use an `IF` to over-ride the (effective) zero value for jan's MonthlyChange with the Sales value.

Comment: @DMM           Basically Id like to automate as much as possible, using a SQL data source which will be updated automatically, and at the same time update all graphs as well. It is also nice to have the "filtering" option in the graphs to provide a nice way of modifying what you want to see. Also, thanks a LOT for the tip about accumulated change being merely the change from january. I don't know how I didn't Think of that, but I'm guessing I'm still in the "Excel way" of thinking.

Comment: @DMM           Please feel free to add your comments as an answer allowing me to accept it. :-)

Comment: @DMM           Do you know a way, by the way, to add a value to "jan" using the difference from jan approach. It looks rather scewed to have an empty value in the middle of a graph. Perhaps it's possible to have the `Sale` date at jan, as that value instead of the difference for only the first month of the year?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150948/discussion-between-dmm-and-cenderze).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments also.

Arithmetically, cumulative change is simply the difference from the first month `jan`. So your "Accumulated Change" column can be defined changing the `(previous)` selection you have previously used in the `Value Field Settings` dialog to `jan`.

You can also drag a field (such as `Sales`) multiple times from the `Pivot Table Field List` to the `Values` area. Each occurrence can be displayed differently by setting its display characteristics differently through the `Value Field Settings` dialog.

[image]

In the picture, the `Sales` field has been dragged 3 times into the `Values` area. The first column in the body of the pivot table , labelled `Sum of Sales`, is just simple a summation of the input values (which simply reproduces the input data because the source data contains only one `Sales` value for each `Month`). The second column (labelled `Sum of Sales2`) is the difference from `(previous)` as described in the question and the third column (`Sum of Sales3`) is the cumulative change (described above).

The labels for the 3 columns in the values area of the Pivot table are the defaults provided by Excel and can be changed into something more meaningful using the `Value Field Settings` dialog